# CalenderAgent: howto allow connection only if needed?

Tags: macos, network, ical, firewall

I use Little Snitch, and there I can see that CalenderAgent still connects to Google and iCloud even if iCal is not running.
For several reasons I want to allow CalenderAgent to make connections only if iCal is running.
I already tried to block it using Little Snitch but it didn't work.

How could solve this... maybe with a shell script?